# How to use Regular Expression Extractor when running JMeter in Non-GUI Mode

Tags: regex, json, jmeter

I am trying to run HTTPs request in JMeter. Using GUI Mode i ran 5000 requests and got responses for them in JSON format.
I want to read a particular field in JSON called "responseCode". For this we need to use Regular expressions. BUt i want to know how to use regular expression in non-GUI Mode.

Comment: Give a sample of your data?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know how to run test in Non-UI mode. If you don't then

```
jmeter -n -t my_test.jmx -l log.jtl -H <my.proxy.server> -P <8000> -u <username> -p <password>
```

Answer to your question is,

1. You can create a script in UI mode.
2. Add all regexes you want to add in your script.
3. Verify it once if they are working or not with small no. of users/threads.
4. Once you are sure that it is working then directly run that test from Non-UI mode. (without modifying it)

Regexes which are present in script will work in Non-UI mode also. JMeter components are independent of UI. They are aligned with script. Add all components that you want in script while record/replay time, perform correlation, parametrization and then schedule script in Non-ui mode.

It should run smoothly as it was running in UI mode.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have developed the script in GUI you can use the same script in non-GUI mode too.

```
jmeter -n -t my_test.jmx -l log.jtl -H my.proxy.server -P 8000
```

In case you are looking for a component with which you can extract the responseCode then you can use the Regular Expression Extractor under Post processors
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor 
for extracting it

Comment: Can u please let me know what do you mean by script, Do we need to write a custom script to parse the JSON and extract the Response Code

Comment: I'm referring to the jmx file as script. I'm assuming u want to extract the responseCode and use it for some kind of conditional logic. For that you can use the Regular Expression Extractor(in the jmx below the sampler where you are getting the response ) and extract the response code